# Vue form submits twice or once and empty

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js, post, core-ui

I am new to javascript and Vue, I have made this simple form using CoreUI Vue and js and I submit the data on PostgreSQL.

In the code  if I Use `v-on:submit="postdata"` it submits once and empty , if I use `v-on:submit.prevent="postdata"` it submits twice the first time empty and the second time right.

Please help I am stuck many days I can't find something wrong,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CCard>
      <CCardHeader>
        <slot name="header"> <CIcon name="cibCcVisa" /> {{ caption }} </slot>
      </CCardHeader>
      <CForm id="myforma" v-on:submit="postdata">
        <CCardBody>
          <CRow>
            <CCol>
              <CInput name="title" label="title" placeholder="Enter Title" v-model="posts.title" id="title" />
            </CCol>
          </CRow>
          <CRow>
            <CCol>
              <CInput label="year" type="date" v-model="posts.year" name="year" />
            </CCol>
          </CRow>

          <CRow>
            <CCol>
              <CInput name="writer" label="writer" placeholder="Enter the writer" :v-model="posts.writer" />
            </CCol>
          </CRow>
          <CRow>
            <CCol sm="12">
              <CInput name="description" label="description" placeholder="Write the description" v-model="posts.description" />
            </CCol>
          </CRow>

          <CRow>
            <CCol lg="6">
              <CSelect label="type" name="type" :options="['1.Books', '2.Comics', '3.NOvels', '4.Writings']" :value.sync="posts.type" />
            </CCol>
          </CRow>
        </CCardBody>

        <CCardFooter>
          <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary"><CIcon name="cil-check-circle" /> Submit</CButton>
          <CButton type="reset" size="sm" color="danger"><CIcon name="cil-ban" /> Reset</CButton>
        </CCardFooter>
      </CForm>
    </CCard>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'forma',
  data(){
    return{
      posts: {
        title: '',
        year :'' ,
        writer:null,
        description:null,
        type: '1.Books'
      },
    }
  },
  props: {
    caption: {
      default: 'Thanasis Form'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    postdata() {
      axios.post('http://localhost/post.php',this.posts).then((response) => {this.posts= response.data;
      console.log(response.data)});
      console.log(this.posts);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

```php
<?php 
include "db.php";   

$received_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

$table= $received_data['title'];
$wri=$received_data['writer'];
    

$result=pg_query($connection,"INSERT INTO tablet (title) VALUES (' $table')");
?>
```

Comment: Since you are new to JavaScript and Vue, I suggest keeping it as simple as possible.  Get rid of coreui for now and just use standard HTML form, etc.  Once you get that working, you can try to add coreui back in.  Also, make sure your PHP web service is working correctly by testing with something like Postman or Insomnia.

Comment: it is for a project of school the teacher wants us to use coreui

Comment: I still suggest getting it working without coreui first, and then if you get it working, add coreui back in, get that working, and then turn in your project with coreui.  Obviously up to you.